# Warning: Date-Time Language Module `nynorsk' not installed

Tags: babel, languages, warnings, datetime2

I am working through the warnings and errors of a project of mine. One error that has been bugging me is in regards to the `datetime2` package. The following code

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[norsk,nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional,calc]{datetime2}
\DTMsetstyle{norsk}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

correctly produces

[image]

However, it also generates the error

> ```
> Package datetime2 Warning: Date-Time Language Module `nynorsk' not installed on input line 1882.
> ```

The warning is clear since there exists no Date-Time Language Module `nynorsk`. Now, nynorsk is just a dialect of norsk, and thus should use precicely the same time and date format as norsk.

- Is there a way to define a language to use the time settings from another language without generating the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `nynorsk` module by making a file `datetime2-nynorsk.ldf` containing

```
\ProvidesDateTimeModule{nynorsk}
\RequireDateTimeModule{norsk}
```

Just put the file in the same directory as your `.tex` file, or in a path contained in `TEXINPUTS`.  Then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk,nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional,calc]{datetime2}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Sample output]

without any warnings.