# datetime, language not supported

Tags: languages, datetime

I want to use the `datetime` package to get the name of the months, but the package does not support one of the languages I am using. I am writing a template (with a `.sty` file), so I want to be able to use different languages. My question is: **How can I define the name of the months for this language that is not supported?**

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[5p,a4paper]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}

\RequirePackage{datetime}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
    % Commands for how a date is displayed:
    \newdateformat{MonthYearDateFormat}{%
        \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR
        }
    \newdateformat{DayMonthYearDateFormat}{%
        \THEDAY \ \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR
        }
    \newdateformat{YearDateFormat}{%
        \THEYEAR
        }

    \patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\parbox[b][36pt]{\linewidth}{\vfill\hfill\textnormal{\today}\hfill\null\vfill}}{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt}{\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\parbox[b][36pt]{\linewidth}{\vfill\hfill\textnormal{\today}\hfill\null\vfill}}{}{}%
    
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{nynorsk}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{title}

\author[University]{O. Nordmann} 
\address[University]{University}

% Date:
%------------------------------------
\newdate{dateName}{19}{04}{2022}
\renewcommand*{\today}{\MonthYearDateFormat\displaydate{dateName}} 
% Options for displaying date: \MonthYearDateFormat,  \DayMonthYearDateFormat or \YearDateFormat
%

\begin{abstract}
abs

\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\appendix
\section{A}

\end{document}
```

This produces the error:

```
Package datetime Warning: No month names provided for language 'nynorsk' on input line 45.
```

I would prefer a solution using datetime over some other solution. I tried using `datetime2`, but I found it simpler to use `datetime`. Is there a way to define the monthnames for the language nynorsk?

**Edit:** The reason I used `datetime` and not `datetime2` is because `datetime2` has no command that displays the monthname of the *currently* selected language. As I want my template to be able to handle multiple languages, I can not define a dateformat using names specific for a language.

Also, the names are basicually the same as for those in the language option `norsk` (which works fine in `datetime`). However, I want the rest of the document to be typset in `nynorsk`. As such I would welcome a solution that uses the names from `norsk` but typsets the rest of the document in `nynorsk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Nynorsk support yourself by patching the relevant commands in the `datetime` configuration file for (Bokmål) Norsk. I checked on [ScriptSource](https://www.scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=entry_detail&uid=fht4hw9r24) and it seems that only the weekday names need changes.

```
\documentclass[5p,a4paper]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[english,nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[norsk]{datetime}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\NewCommandCopy{\monthnamenynorsk}{\monthnamenorsk}
\NewCommandCopy{\dayofweeknameidnynorsk}{\dayofweeknameidnorsk}
\NewCommandCopy{\shortdayofweeknameidnynorsk}{\shortdayofweeknameidnorsk}
\NewCommandCopy{\datenynorsk}{\datenorsk}

\patchcmd{\dayofweeknameidnynorsk}{Mandag}{Måndag}{}{}
\patchcmd{\dayofweeknameidnynorsk}{Tirsdag}{Tysdag}{}{}
\patchcmd{\dayofweeknameidnynorsk}{L\o{}rdag}{Laurdag}{}{}
\patchcmd{\shortdayofweeknameidnorsk}{Man}{Mån}{}{}
\patchcmd{\shortdayofweeknameidnorsk}{Tir}{Tys}{}{}
\patchcmd{\shortdayofweeknameidnorsk}{L\o{}r}{Lau}{}{}

% Commands for how a date is displayed:
\newdateformat{MonthYearDateFormat}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR
}
\newdateformat{DayMonthYearDateFormat}{%
  \THEDAY \ \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR
}
\newdateformat{YearDateFormat}{%
  \THEYEAR
}

\patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}
  {\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt}
  {\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par
   \parbox[b][36pt]{\linewidth}{\vfill\hfill\textnormal{\today}\hfill\null\vfill}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}
  {\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt}
  {\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par
   \parbox[b][36pt]{\linewidth}{\vfill\hfill\textnormal{\today}\hfill\null\vfill}}
  {}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{title}

\author[University]{O. Nordmann} 
\address[University]{University}

% Date:
%------------------------------------
\newdate{dateName}{19}{05}{2022}
\renewcommand*{\today}{\MonthYearDateFormat\displaydate{dateName}} 
% Options for displaying date: \MonthYearDateFormat,  \DayMonthYearDateFormat or \YearDateFormat
%

\begin{abstract}
abs

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}\today\end{otherlanguage}

\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\appendix
\section{A}

\end{document}
```

(I changed from April to May to better show the difference).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` is obsolete and has been replaced by `datetime2`, so I suggest you use that. Language and regional support is then provided by independently maintained and installed modules. There is a module for “Norsk” too (probably Bokmål, granted, but shouldn't be too hard to make it work): https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-norsk

Comment: That said, have you seen this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521181/warning-date-time-language-module-nynorsk-not-installed ?

Comment: `datetime2` has no command to display the monthname of the current language. What I want in my template is to display the name of the current selected language (eighter nynorsk or english).

Answer (score -1):

Running your MWE I get

```
Package datetime warning: no month names provided for language 'nynorsk' on input line 48.
```

I changed your MWE to use the `datetime2` package (effectively the replacement of `datetime`) and got (among many other messages)

```
Package datetime2 Warning: Date-Time Language module 'nynorsk' not installed on input line 1913.
```

Knowing nothing about `datetime` it seems to me that it would be best for you to ask for help from the author Nicola I. C. Talbot http://www.dickimaw-books.com who is usually very good at responding. What is the difference between language 'nynorsk' and other Nordic languages? Perhaps you would be able to produce a Data-Time Language module 'nynorsk'?

Comment: There are basically two separate written standards in Norway, Bokmål ("Book language") vs. Nynorsk ("New Norwegian") which uses a reformed spelling etc. Unlike, say, German where the "new" orthography has been pretty much universally adopted, I understand that "Bokmål" remains the preferred written standard of a majority of Norwegians by a rather large margin.

Comment: I could use the monthnames from `norsk` (the other variant of norwegian, but I want the document to be typset in `nynorsk`.